# Unable to install requirements.txt. TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, python-wheel, requirements.txt

After git pulling upstream main from a repo I'm working on with about 10 other developers, I've been trying to pip install -Ur requirements.txt but it keeps coming up with this error and I've tried every answer I could find online including --upgrade pip but it's just not just working, please what do I do

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Price-compare-project-team-21-Backend> pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref==3.5.2 in c:\users\user\desktop\price-compare-project-team-21-backend\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.5.2)
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
Collecting bs4==0.0.1
  Using cached bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
   `enter code here`     File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3819a79z\bs4_ea1a5f0c8d014580b2a9beff5de51827\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          setup(
        File "c:\users\user\desktop\price-compare-project-team-21-backend\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "c:\users\user\desktop\price-compare-project-team-21-backend\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 147, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
        File "c:\users\user\desktop\price-compare-project-team-21-backend\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 474, in __init__
          for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
      TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: can you post your setup.py file?  The error is in that file.

Comment: Does it work with beautifulsoup4==4.9.0 instead of beautifulsoup4==4.11.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

[bs4](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/) is a dummy package for [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/). I think you can remove safely that package from requirements.txt and install everything else.

Comment: Actually now I'm unable to activate virtualenv because I deleted the whole folder and cloned the github repo all over again #sigh. It says ' PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)'

Comment: Create a new virtualenv with `python -m venv venv` then activate the venv and then install the packages from requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

It is cause by `importlib_metadata` package as mention in https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata/issues/331

Resolve: upgrade your importlib_metadata to latest version (current 4.11.3)

If `pip` cannot be used due to such error, you can use conda to upgrade your package.

```
conda install -c main importlib_metadata==4.11.3
```

You should upgrade package related to the error (`setuptools`, `twine`, and `pip` itself)